# AWS SAM/Cloudformation "Malformed integration at path' error

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I get the following error when trying to deploy lambda and API gateway configuration

> "malformed integration at path /profile/v1. (Service:
>   AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException"

What can cause this error and how can it be resolved.

---

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: v1
  title: ProfileAPI
paths:
  "/profile/v1":
    get:
      tags:
      - Values
      operationId: ProfileV1Get
      consumes: []
      produces:
      - text/plain
      - application/json
      - text/json
      parameters: []
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Success
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              type: string
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        httpMethod: post
        type: aws_proxy
        uri:
          Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${ProfileFunction.Arn}/invocations
definitions: {}
```

Comment: I have the same error, have you already figured it out?

Answer (score 1):

Got a final working setup working with AWS Support that y'all might be interested in:

> When we reference the cloudformation resource details in the external swagger template, we do not get the resource details and hence receive the above error. For example: “ Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${LambdaFunction.Arn}/invocations “ will not work when you try to create API gateway integration endpoint uri in swagger definition using resource : "LambdaFunction.Arn” (which is the CloudFormation resource).
>
> In order to resolve these issues, I made the below changes in the cloudformation template:
>
> To reference the swagger file in the cloudformation template, I uploaded the swagger template in the s3 bucket and then used the below definition. I used :

```
    ZazzoAPI:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
        Properties:
            StageName: Prod
            Variables:
                LambdaFunctionName: !Ref LambdaFunction
            #Configure API settings and options
            MethodSettings: [{
                LoggingLevel: "INFO",
                MetricsEnabled: True ,
                HttpMethod: "GET",
                ResourcePath: "/"
            }]
            DefinitionBody:
                'Fn::Transform':
                  Name: 'AWS::Include'
                  Parameters:
                        Location: "s3://s3.code-deploy/swagger_SAM.yaml"
```

> The AWS::Include transform lets you create a reference to a transform snippet in an Amazon S3 bucket. It allows to reference the cloudformation resource details in an external swagger file. You can refer to the documentation at [1] for more details regarding "AWS::Include” Transform.
>
> I then checked the swagger template and could see that you are using shorthand notations for specifying the integration uri. However, "AWS::Include” does not currently support using shorthand notations for YAML snippets as mentioned in the documentation [2]. Therefore, I used the intrinsic function "Fn::Sub" and was able to reference the required cloudformation parameters in the swagger template.

---

### Previous definition:

```
uri: !Sub "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${LambdaFunction.Arn}/invocations”
```

---

### New definition:

```
uri: 
      Fn::Sub: "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${LambdaFunction.Arn}/invocations"
```

## References:

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/create-reusable-transform-function-snippets-and-add-to-your-template-with-aws-include-transform.html
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/create-reusable-transform-function-snippets-and-add-to-your-template-with-aws-include-transform.html#aws-include-transform-remarks
3. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apigateway-stage-methodsetting.html